# HOW TO CALL THIS PROCEDURE?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

Here I'm Creating procedure to inner join two tables.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TBL_EMPLOYEE_PROJECT(
    EMP_ID   IN  TBL_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
    CUR      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
    BEGIN
    OPEN CUR FOR
    SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_ID,
    E.FIRST_NAME FIRST_NAME,
    E.LAST_NAME LAST_NAME,
    E.MIDDLE_NAME MIDDLE_NAME,
    E.SALARY SALARY,
    E.DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE_OF_BIRTH,
    E.DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_ID,
    E.INSERTED_BY INSERTED_BY,
    E.INSERTED_DT INSERTED_DT,
    E.UPDATE_BY UPDATE_BY,
    E.UPDATED_DT UPDATED_DT,
    E.DELETED_BY DELETED_BY,
    E.DELETED_DT DELETED_DT,
    E.MANAGER_ID MANAGER_ID,
    D.DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_ID_0,
    D.DEPARTMENT_NAME DEPARTMENT_NAME,
    D.DEPARTMENT_LOCATION DEPARTMENT_LOCATION
    FROM  TBL_EMPLOYEE E
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D
    ON ( E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID )
    WHERE  E.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP_ID;
    END;
```

But Don't Know How To Call This Stored Procedure.
Please Tell How To Call This Procedure

Comment: All-Caps is commonly perceived as "shouting". Shouting at people is not considered particularly polite in most cultures.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare
    returned_refcursor   SYS_REFCURSOR :=  Null;
Begin
    BL_EMPLOYEE_PROJECT(some_emp_id, returned_refcursor);
    -- variable returned_refcursor now has a pointer to the CUR from procedure
End;
```

Here is a simple example

```
create or replace PROCEDURE AA(
    EMP_ID   IN  VARCHAR2,
    CUR      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
    BEGIN
    OPEN CUR FOR
        Select * From
            (
                SELECT '12' "ID", 'Name for 12' "NAME" FROM  DUAL UNION ALL
                SELECT '13' "ID", 'Name for 13' "NAME" FROM  DUAL
            )
        WHERE ID = EMP_ID;
    END;
    
-- Use it
Declare
    returned_refcursor   SYS_REFCURSOR :=  Null;
    myId   VarChar2(10);
    myName VarChar2(20);
Begin
    AA('12', returned_refcursor);
    -- variable returned_refcursor now has a pointer to the CUR from procedure
    Fetch returned_refcursor InTo myID, myName;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myId);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myName);
End

-- Result
-- anonymous block completed
-- 12
-- Name for 12
```

Comment: But How To Show OUTPUT ? DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(returned_refcursor); ?

Comment: Read this https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/888365/pl-sql-101-understanding-ref-cursors . REFCURSOR does not contain data, just a pointer to cursor. You have to fetch the data.

Comment: Yeah, But I Need To Show Output Data . In That Case Whai I Need To Do ?

Comment: Folow the example...